# Forward 'Log Streaming' to external source

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-monitoring

I was wondering if there's an option to forward the 'Log Streaming' output to a 3rd party.
We use various providers and host all of our application logs under one roof, thus we'd like to forward Azure Functions log to the same place. 
I see there's an option to *Log Streaming* the console and would like to forward it to our 3rd party vendor. (Similar to 'Stream to AWS Lambda')

Thanks!